# HTML not formatting in mail function

Tags: php, html

I am using the following code:

```
$message = "Hi ".$user.
  ",\r\rThe following names are on the guestlist for <b>".$night.
  "</b> on ".$date2.":\r\r". $user ."<br>". implode(", ", $names).
  "\r\rThank you for using Guestvibe.";

mail($email, "Your Guestvibe list", $message);
```

The carriage returns in PHP are working fine, but neither the `<b>` or `<br>` tags are coming out. Is it just my mail client (Apple Mail) playing up, or is there a fix for this?

Comment: Are you sending the mail as text-only?

Comment: stop using the horribly underpowered mail() function and switch to one of the well used classes which will make this all a lot easier.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are sending the e-mail as text only not HTML, I believe you need to set these headers:

```
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8' . "\r\n";
```

as in [example #4 of the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php).

Answer (score 5):

PHP's `mail` function sends plaintext mail by default.

See the nr.4 example at [mail's manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) for the correct way to send HTML mail.

Answer (score 3):

You need to add your headers:

```
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

mail($email, "Your Guestvibe list", $message, $headers);
```

Comment: I would probaby go for another carset, UTF-8 would probably be better ;)

Answer (score 1):

You should firstly wrap the whole message into:

```
<html><head></head><body> msg </body></html>
```

Plus headers from m.edmondson post.